# return 2 or more variables separately from looped $.post()

Tags: php, jquery

I'm currently developing a `textarea` that whatever pasted after the push of button, it will be added to the database. Setting aside the database function aside.
I would like to achieve is:

- Return the number of records that is successfully posted
- Return the number of records which was not inserted telling its already a duplicate

jquery code

```
$(function(){
$('#sw').click(function(){
  if($("#txta").val().length>0) 
  {
    var h=confirm("Are you sure?");
    if(h==true)
    {
        var fld=$("#txta").val().split('\n');
        $.each(fld, function(){
          $.post('up.php',
          { 'ldta': this.split('\t') },
          function(data) {
            $('#out').append(data);
          }
          );
        });
        alert('Upload completed');
    }
    else
      alert("Cancelled");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Textarea is empty.");
    $('#out').html('');
  }
});
});
```

php

```
 $setsu = dbSetsuzoku();//connection string stored on separate file
    $ldta=$_POST['ldta'];
    $qSql='';
    $dtHK=0;
    $qSql="SELECT * FROM bet WHERE bet_id=".$ldta[0];
    $stmt = $setsu->query($qSql);
    $rwk=$stmt->rowCount();
    if ($rwk==0)
    {
      //post to database code..
    }
    else
       $lkaku.=$lines.", ";//$lines tell the line that was not added
if(!is_null($lkaku))
{
  $hj='<table><tr style="background-color:#FF0000">';//displays the record that was not added table red in color..
  foreach ($ldta as $key => $value) {
          $hj.='<td>'.$value.'</td>';
      }
  $hj.='</tr></table>';
  echo $hj;
}
else
{
  $hj='<table border="1"><tr>';//displays the successfully added record/line
  foreach ($ldta as $key => $value) {
          $hj.='<td>'.$value.'</td>';
      }
  $hj.='</tr></table>';
  echo $hj;
}
```

I noticed that whatever echoed on php it is get by the $.post() function on the part

```
function(data) {
    $('#out').append(data);
}
```

Workarounds or ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

using array in your php code. And using return json.

```
$data['first'] = "firstdata";
$data['second'] = array(0=>"iam",1=>"cool");

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer. The data that is passed by jquery on part $.post('up.php', { 'ldta': this.split('\t') }, is already an array. I can use such as $ldta[0],$ldta[1] and so on and but I'd like to use the variables $dtHK and $lines as well. And since the values of $ldta is inside the loop, the output that appears on the page will be repeated say dtHk is 10 (means 10 records successfully inserted) '10' will be displayed 10 times together with the <table> that has been created. How would I get the values of $dtHK and $lines outside the $.each loop?